# How to retain class of variable in `tapply`?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose my data frame is set up like so:

```
X <- data.frame(
  id = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  dt = as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'))
)
```

and I want to populate a variable of the id-specific minimum value of date `dt`

Doing: `X$dtmin <- with(X, tapply(dt, id, min)[id])` gives a numeric because the `simplify=T` in `tapply` has cast the value to numeric. Why has it done this? Setting `simplify=F` returns a list which each element in the list has the desired data structure, but populating the variable in my dataframe `X` casts these back to numeric. Yet calling `as.Date(<output>, origin='1970-01-01')` seems needlessly verbose. How can I retain the data structure of `dt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
X$dtmin <- with(X, do.call("c", tapply(dt, id, min, simplify = FALSE)[id]))
```

---

Or use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
X %>%
   mutate(dtmin = min(dt), .by = "id")
```

Comment: Thanks, it really seems like this is the only way to go. I prefer base R, and created a wrapped based on option1 .

Comment: @AdamO With `Date` class, there is a constraint with coercion as the storage mode is numeric